# How not to resubmit form when the user goes back to the page where he clicked a link that was from a selected combo box?

Tags: php, html, back, location-href

I know, confusing title. Apologies. Anyway, I have a page where the user selects from a combo box to view another set of data. In the loaded page depending on the selection of the user from the combo box, there is a link that the user will click which is the "VIEW", and after that, he can go back to the previous page. My problem is when he clicks the back arrow from his browser, it shows "Confirm form resubmission". How can I avoid that and just let the user go back to the page where the loaded page is shown?

Like when click Accepted Requests from the combo box and click a link from the loaded page, when I want to go back, it will still be in the same page with the list of Accepted Requests. Hope you understood me.

I'm not sure if you guys need to see my code for the combo box and what it will show, but i'll post it anyway:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
            <select name="approvalstatus">
            <option>Select record to view</option>
            <option value="AcceptedRequests">Accepted Requests</option>
            <option value="AcceptedAnnouncement">Accepted Announcement</option>
            </select>&nbsp;
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="View Record" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"/><br>

<?php
include 'dbcontroller.php';
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $selected_stat = $_POST['approvalstatus'];
    if($selected_stat=='AcceptedReq'){
        // my query here
        ?>

        List of Accepted Requests
        //list of data here
        <a href="view_accepted_request.php?view_id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" >VIEW</a>
      <?php             
      }
      $conn->close();
      ?>    
    <?php
    }
else if( // my accepted announcement code here){
  }
}

</form>
```

Comment: The very simple reason this is happening is because you're using POST. Browsers will try to re-submit anything that was send through POST when the user browses back on your website. If you simply use GET instead, the issue will be solved.

Comment: yeah, but i can't use GET because the selected option will not load the page.. thanks tho. @icecub

Comment: Can you edit your question and include the Javscript or jQuery part that loads the new webpage?

Comment: oh, thanks for reminding me about ajax, I forgot that I didn't use it here, it was in my first trial, but with the code above, I just used PHP. I will edit it. @icecub

Comment: No problem. I don't mind helping you figure out how to solve the issue, but to be able to do that, I need all the relevant code :)

Comment: okay. will post my entire code . thanks!  @icecub

Comment: Don't! Lets move this to a chat. The entire code is way to much for here. Just click the "continue this discussion in chat" underneath this comment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110925/discussion-between-icecub-and-emvee).